# Remove "Always use this app to open files"

Tags: windows-10

While i was messing around trying to find a way to make a shortcut i accidently clicked "Google chrome" for .url now the shortcuts for my games don't work, before the default was nothing, i don't know how to set it back. Im on windows 10

Comment: Go to Settings, Apps, Default Apps, App by type (long list), scroll down for each extension you want and remove Chrome. That should work.

Comment: Also, if resetting the app in File Type settings, something may have been corrupted in the setting.  Try this article to see if it helps:  https://techcult.com/how-to-remove-file-type-associations-in-windows-10/

Comment: What do you mean by "Remove Chrome" i only have a option to choose and app not remove an app though,

Comment: If you cannot remove Chrome, try changing to the app you want, or try the article I posted.

Comment: @John for the .url before it was set to nothing idk how to set it back i saw a tutorial using regedit but i didn't have one of the folders they had, Also wich article?

Comment: The article in my comment second from the top here.

Comment: @John thanks i have really wanting to play rocket league for a while but it kept saying an error found out it was beacuse of this

Comment: Another thing you can try is the following:  Open File Explorer, navigate to the file for Rocket League. Right Click on it and select Open With. That should then provide a More Apps list (down arrow). See if you can re-associate your program this way. It works here.